# how to handle change on the input field,and debounce function reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to be able to change the value attribute inside an input tag dynamically  but also to set the initial value to some text

I would like to send an API request only after the user stopped typing, therefore I'm using a debounce function, the problem is I'm not able to keep updating the input field as the user type.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tag: 'art',
      searchTerm: 'art'

    };
  }

  callApi = debounce ((searchTerm) =>{
        this.setState({searchTerm:searchTerm});
  },5000) 

  onSearchHandler = searchTerm =>{
    this.setState({tag:searchTerm})
    this.callApi(searchTerm)
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app-root">
        <div className="app-header"> 
          <h2>Flickr Gallery</h2>
          <input 
              className="app-input" 
              onChange={event => {this.onSearchHandler(event.target.value)}}
              value ={this.state.tag}
              />
        </div>
        <Gallery tag={this.state.searchTerm}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

if I'll delete the value attribute from the input field then everything is fine, so how can I add the value attribute and still change it on demand, but send the request only after X Seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are debouncing the update of your state when you only want to debounce the api request. You will want to always update your state on change and then debounce your api request. e.g.:

```
callApi = debounce(() => {
  /** your API call */
}, 5000)

onSearchHandler = searchTerm => {
  this.setState({ tag:searchTerm });
  this.callApi();
}
```

The reason is because by setting/updating the value based on state you have created a controlled component (see the React [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) documentation for more details) and you were debouncing the updating of its value.

Comment: so, if I have a callAPI function inside my Gallary component, i should call it in there, right? how can I pass the call to the gallery component callAPI function from the app controller?

Comment: If your Gallery component is searching based on its tag prop changing, you will want to separate your search term value and tag. In that case, you would:
- setState({ searchTerm }) in the onChange callback
- use the searchTerm state as your input value
- debounce a second call to update your tag state

Comment: so if i understood correctly something like this (code is edit), can i ask how did you add code to comments clocks?

Comment: Yeah, your code edits seem to align. Code in comments can only inline items by using back ticks - see details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77485/code-formating-in-comments)